# Remove PrettyPrint Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yelp

I have a problem with the Javascript  -

```
 $.ajax({
 'url': message.action,
 'data': parameterMap,
 'cache': true,
 'dataType': 'jsonp',
 'jsonpCallback': 'cb',
 'success': function(data, textStats, XMLHttpRequest) {
   console.log(data);
   var output = prettyPrint(data);
   $("body").append(output);
  }
 });
```

This outputs the JSON using prettyprint. How do I output plain json (without prettyprint)?
I tried

```
$("body").append(data)
```

Nothing showed up.

PS: I am using the Example Code provided by YELP.com . This is the link to the entire code - https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/js/search.html

Comment: What do you mean by `output`? Use `console.log(data)`.

Comment: $("body").append should have yielded `[object Object]` unless your data is an array.

Comment: VisioN - I just need the plain JSON inside the the HTML Body as I need to parse the data. Like `<body>{...}</body>`.I don get anything If I use just console.log(data).

Comment: Yes my data is an Array and prettyprint does not display it..

Comment: Try `$("body").append(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: Ansari - Thanks a lot! This is what I wanted!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For modern browsers that support natively JSON encoding/decoding you can use

```
var output = JSON.stringify(data);
```

For browsers that do not support it, you can find an implementation at http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is an actual object here, you're right, PrettyPrint won't show much. I would recommend using your browser's `console.log()` command, or if you really want to "print" it you could take a look at the actual response text. [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/adonaf/7/edit#preview)

```
$.ajax({
    'url': 'http://jsbin.com/ojesuv',
    'dataType': 'jsonp',
    'jsonpCallback': 'fake',
    'success': function(data, textStats, XMLHttpRequest) {
        console.log(data);
        $("body").append(XMLHttpRequest.responseText)
    }
});
```